# LibGDX textures rendering black

Tags: libgdx, textures

I know that there are many questions related to this, but none are relevant to my problem.

So, I have a TiledMap which has 2 layers for boxes in my game - one for the box graphics and one for the box objects. Now, I want to get the textures of all the boxes because I want to be able to draw them anywhere freely. So I wrote some code to find out which tiles a given rectangle (attained from the object layer of the boxes) is covering (this code works fine). Then, from the graphics layer (TileMapTileLayer), I am accessing the textures in those tiles and drawing them to a single texture using Pixmaps. Finally, I store this texture. However, when I render these textures, they are black. Heres the code -

```
        TiledMapTileLayer boxLayer = (TiledMapTileLayer) (map.getLayers().get(2)); // this is the graphics layer
        ArrayList<Vector2> cells;
        Texture tex;
        Pixmap pmap, pmapScld;
        int numCols, numRows, cellNum;
        int boxInd = 0;
        FileTextureData texData;
        StaticTiledMapTile tile;
        
        for(RectangleMapObject boxBody : map.getLayers().get(3).getObjects().getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)) { //object layer
            bounds = boxBody.getRectangle();
            cells = getOccupiedCells(bounds);
            numCols = (int) cells.get(0).x; //I have stored the width and height of the texture 
            numRows = (int) cells.get(0).y; //in tiles in the first Vector2 of the Array
            tex = new Texture(numCols * tileWidthOrg, numRows * tileHeightOrg, Format.RGBA8888);
            cellNum = 1;
            
            System.out.println(cells);
            
            for(int i = 0 ; i < numCols ; i++) {
                for(int j = 0 ; j < numRows ; j++) {
                    tile = (StaticTiledMapTile) (boxLayer.getCell((int) cells.get(cellNum).x, (int) cells.get(cellNum).y).getTile());
                    texData = (FileTextureData) tile.getTextureRegion().getTexture().getTextureData();
                    
                    texData.prepare();
                    pmap = texData.consumePixmap();
                    
                    //pmapScld = new Pixmap(tileWidthScld, tileHeightScld, pmap.getFormat());
                    //pmapScld.drawPixmap(pmap, 0, pmap.getHeight(), pmap.getWidth(), pmap.getHeight(), 
                            //0, pmapScld.getHeight(), pmapScld.getWidth(), pmapScld.getHeight());
                    
                    tex.draw(pmap, i * tileWidthOrg, j * tileHeightOrg);
                    pmap.dispose();
                    texData.disposePixmap();
                    //pmapScld.dispose();
                    cellNum++;
                }
            }
            contactListener.addBox(new GBox(world, tex, bounds, boxInd));
            tex.dispose();
            boxInd++;
        }
```

The code for rendering these boxes -

```
for(GBox box : contactListener.boxes) {
    box.render(sb);
}
```

```
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.draw(tex, body.getPosition().x - width / 2, body.getPosition().y - height / 2, width, height);
        //System.out.println("rendering box " + index + " at position " + body.getPosition());
}
```

Comment: I think you need to do way more debugging yourself. For instance when you create pixmaps you can read pixel colors back, so maybe sample pixels to check that they are being set roughly how you expect. But, although I can't really tell the structure of your code, you are trying to draw 'tex'. The top box of code where I see 'tex' being created and drawn onto, you then immediately do a tex.dispose(). Why?

Comment: I basically want to send 'tex' to my box constructor and the instance will use that texture to render itself.

Edit : I tried removing the dispose line and somehow it is rendering properly as expected... but only the first box is rendering. The others are not.